# Parallax image loads fine, but jumps to center when hovered over

Tags: css, header, background-image, centering, parallax

I've got this peculiar bug I've been trying to fix today—-still no luck.
If you look at the example below,

http://vitaliyg.com/alpha/hire/

Here's what happens. The full-width background image loads in the correct position, centered along the y axis. Then when we hover over the image, the whole image jumps over to the middle, and slowly adjusts itself back to it's normal desired position.

What's causing this is `left: 50%; margin-left: -960px;`. This allows us to center the image correctly to begin with. If we didn't have this CSS, the hover wouldn't jump, but the image would load anchoring itself on the top left of the browser.

In the link above, the red box is the content div. The blue box is some text that will be parallaxing with the `background-image`.

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

1. Make the `background-image` appear centered.
2. When the user hovers over the `background-image`, it would not jump to the middle of the page.
3. And lastly, decrease the width of which the user would be able to "parallax" on the x axis. The way it is now, is that the user can see from side to side of the image if patient enough. I want the parallax to be very subtle.

Also, I'm using jParallax, found here:
http://stephband.info/jparallax/

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you set the position via CSS for the background image, it seems jQuery Parallax plugin alters those settings. The solution then is to apply those settings after the jQuery Parallax has dealt with that parallax layer.

First, remove the `margin-left` and `left` from your `.parallax-layer#background` class.

```css
.parallax-layer#background {
  background-image: url('../images/bg.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center bottom;
  width: 1920px;
  height: 620px;
}
```

Ideally, center the blue box using the same method (unless you want it partially off screen). I've also removed non essential CSS based on your HTML.

```css
.parallax-layer#tagline {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

Finally, add the CSS rules that were removed from the **background** and **tagline** selectors so they are applied after jQuery Parallax has manipulated those items.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#parallax .parallax-layer')
    .parallax({
        mouseport: jQuery('body')
    });
  jQuery('#background').css({marginLeft: "-960px", left: "50%", bottom: "0px"});
  jQuery('#tagline').css({marginLeft: "-200px", left: "50%"});
});
```

You no longer will see the large white section (body background color) to the left of the background image when the mouse enters the viewport.

This **jQuery Parallax** plugin aligns everything top/left by design. If the mouse enters the 
viewport from the right of the blue box, that box animates to that location correctly.

However, should the mouse enter from the left side of the blue box, that box will 'jump' to the cursors location. You might consider removing the last jQuery line above so the blue box is top/left upon browser load or use a lower percentage value like **`25%`**.

---

For those that landed on this Question/Answer and wanted some real markup to work with, I have set up two jsFiddles. One jsFiddle duplicated the problem and the other has the solution as shown above.

[**Original Problem - jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/UG4Sq/embedded/result/)
[**Fixed Applied - jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/UG4Sq/1/embedded/result/)

Both jsFiddles are in full screen mode so the Parallax effects can be seen.

**Instructions to view Original Problem:**
**1.** Launch the above Original Problem jsFiddle Link.
**2.** Press the jsFiddle Play Button, being careful not to enter the viewport. If the blue box moves in any way... you've entered the viewport so press the play button again.
**3.** Enter from the top/left of the viewport and you will see the problem... the HTML Body (white color) is seen as the background image readjusts itself.
**4.** Press the Play Button at any time to reset the webpage.

To see the Fixed Applied, either launch the link above or at the Browsers Address Bar modify the URL so you see revision 1 of that jsFiddle. (i.e., `http://jsfiddle.net/UG4Sq/1/embedded/result/` )

The blue box indicates via text which jsFiddle your viewing. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks very much for taking a look at this! This solved my issue. The only thing I can think of now—-is there a way to tell jParallax to align the background-image center bottom?

Comment: Please see edited jQuery `#background` selector above. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks you for your persistence! I've plugged in the `bottom: "0px"` but it didn't seem to resolve the issue—-the image still snaps to the top left. I've slowed down the animation and so you can better see. I've uploaded the changes to http://alpha.vitaliyg.com/hire/ did I miss anything?

Comment: Ah, I see your point buy my previous explanation wasn't clear (See "However..." above). The recent change I provided was to align the bottom of the background image correctly. Calculations are made once the mouse enters the viewport, so it looks like you have to work with the way that plugin operates, but I do have two ideas that should alleviate that problem... that's to work with it. Example 1: Have other parallax content before the section with the centered image. This other content can be tiled / solid for example. Then, since the mouse cursor is in the viewport.. any snaps aren't seen.

Comment: Example 2: Have the entire webpage covered by a fading screen that requires interactivity from the user to press a button. This page is placed on top of the exiting parallax site so in essence, the snap is not seen since it occurs under this screen.

Comment: Example 3: How about showing a parallax iframe? The background image is then markup of that webpage to be centered. I don't have a demo for that, but just an idea. Maybe there's another idea or a different Parallax plugin that works better for centered images. Cheers!

Comment: Here's a Quick and Dirty Demo for Example 2: [**Fixed with Button - jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/UG4Sq/2/embedded/result/). If you come with with an idea that works for you, kindly post a reply of what worked. Cheers!